# Prometheus/Alertmanager: routing alerts to two different emails

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have following Alertmanager configuration:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 1m
route:
  # A default receiver
  receiver: "EmailNotifications-EPG"
  routes:
    - receiver: "EmailNotifications-EPG"
      matchers:
        - alertname="EPG_build_too_long"
    - receiver: "EmailNotifications-APP"
      matchers:
        - alertname="APP_build_too_long"
receivers:
- name: "EmailNotifications-EPG"
  email_configs:
  - to: e1@company.com,e2@company.com
    from: "Monitor <monitor@company.com>"
    smarthost: mail.company.com:25
    auth_username: monitor@company.com
    auth_identity: monitor@company.com
    auth_password: "..."
    send_resolved: true
- name: "EmailNotifications-APP"
  email_configs:
  - to: e1@company.com,e3@company.com
    from: "Monitor <monitor@company.com>"
    smarthost: mail.company.com:25
    auth_username: monitor@company.com
    auth_identity: monitor@company.com
    auth_password: "..."
    send_resolved: true
```

I would like that in case of alert "EPG_build_too_long" email alert would be sent to the receiver "EmailNotifications-EPG". And in the case of alert "APP_build_too_long" the receiver would be "EmailNotifications-APP". However in the case of both alerts the default receiver "EmailNotifications-EPG" gets emails. Why? (And another small question - is it OK to move the common email configuration part, like `from:`, `smarthost` etc till the end - to the `global` section?)

Comment: Wrong sites for configuration question.

Comment: Answer to small question: it's OK if you name them `smtp_from` and `smtp_smarthost`. See details on allowed global confog [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#file-layout-and-global-settings)